# Facebook login javascript sdk not working with publish_actions scope

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing web app using like button graph api in localhost but it not work correctly.
When User click on like button, if fb login status is 'connected' then it calling graph api create like object to make like user like url. Problem: status of user is 'connected' but graph api always response "Requires extended permission: publish_actions" when calling to create object - like url.

Here is my code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    FB.init({
        appId: MY_APP_ID,
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/vi_VN/all.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

/////////////////////////
// Login
////////////////////////
function fbLogin() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                //something
            });
        }
    },{scope: 'publish_actions,publish_stream'});
}

/////////////////////////
// btnLike heart click
////////////////////////
jQuery('.hit').click(function() {
    var current = jQuery(this);
    var postId = current.attr('id');
    var url = current.parent().attr('data-href');
    var class_string = current.attr('class');
    var class_array = class_string.split(' ');

    if (class_array.indexOf("liked") != -1) {  // found : liked
    } else { // not found : not liked
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                FB.api('me/og.likes', 'post', {
                    /*test*/
                    object : getTestPermalink(url),
                }, function(res) {
                    if (res.id) { //hit like successful
                        jQuery.post(
                            MyAjax.ajaxurl, 
                            { action: 'set_post_likes', postId: postId }, 
                            function(result) {
                                current.addClass('liked');
                                current.parent().children('.count').html(result.split('-')[0]);
                            }
                        );
                    }
                });
            } else {
                fbLogin();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Can someone help me?
sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `publish_stream` is deprecated (since years?), you only need publish_actions.
- You are calling `FB.login` in an asynchronous callback function. You must call it directly on user interaction (mouse click), NOT in the callback of `FB.getLoginStatus`.

That being said, the permission error usually pops up if you aren´t trying with a user who is Admin, Developer or Tester of your App. `publish_actions` needs do get approved by Facebook before any other user can authorize it. Check out the Login Review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Comment: try with an app admin/developer or go through the review process. and of course remove "publish_stream".